# Gnome Terminal - keypad enter just beeps

Tags: gnome3, gnome-terminal

I just installed ubuntu GNOME 16.04.  So far, so good.

When I run "GNOME terminal", I can do the all the things.  But when asked to press "Enter", and I press the button labeled "Enter" on my kepboard near the keypad, it just does an error squirt-beep.

If I press the button above right shift (labeled  <-|), it works.

How can I get the Keypad's "Enter" button to work in gnome terminal?

Thanks!

**Update** this fixed itself (rather I have no idea what fixed it).  It was a new install: zsh, oh-my-zsh, custom profiles, software, 20 reboots, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two <kbd>*Enter*</kbd> keys are different.  The one above the right-shift key sends a carriage-return character (which the terminal driver translates to line-feed as *newline*), while the other may send an escape sequence when the keypad application mode is enabled.  Your instructions meant the former (unless the application uses curses, for example).

If you are trying to use a *curses* (or ncurses) application, you still are not guaranteed that you can use the two interchangeably.  Some developers are confused by the difference, and ignore `KEY_ENTER` when they notice that the <kbd>*Enter*</kbd> key on the keyboard sends just a carriage return.

Along with that, some terminal descriptions have been written (no surprise) which equate `kent` (the terminfo name for `KEY_ENTER`) with carriage return **or** line feed.  A lot of those are for obscure terminals which you probably do not use (and they represent a minority of the terminal descriptions).  For xterm, `kent` is assigned to the escape sequence.  [It's been there a while](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#t19980509) (predating gnome-terminal):

```
# 9.11.3 (Thu Nov  9 12:14:40 EST 1995):
#       * Added kspd=\E[P, kcbt=\E[Z, to linux entry, changed kbs back to ^H.
#       * Added kent=\EOM to xterm entry.
```

Comment: In addition to this, the questioner might be looking for something as simple as _You run `printf '\e[?66l'` to set DECNKM mode off or `printf '\e>'` (DECKPNM)._

Comment: The terminal's initialized with that *off*.  OP is running some half-baked application.

Comment: @ThomasDickey you don't know that and I wouldn't call gnome terminal, bash, or zsh half-baked.

Comment: If you clarify *what* you were running when asked to press *enter*, that would be helpful.

Comment: @ThomasDickey  Aha!  In bash, I remember this command: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom`

Comment: That particular script doesn't change the keypad mode (perhaps some prior step did that without cleanup).